# How to count "in stock" and also "out of stock" in layered navigation as per attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, sidebar

I am trying to show count for all products "in stock" and also "out of stocks" in sidebar.

I used bellow code but its not working.

```
$size = $productCollection->getSize();
$itemData[] = [
                'label' => $this->tagFilter->filter($option['label']),
                'value' => $value,
                'count' => $size
            ];
```